# How to Access/marshall char *variable from dll import in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop, com-interop

I need to access functionality from  win32 dll , for that I am using [dllimport] in C# code.

what exact method signature i need to create with [dllimport]  for the following c++ methods

```
void GetGeneratedKey(char *code, int len, char *key)
```

pls help in this.

Thanks

nRk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends highly on what is happening to the variables `key` and `code` in the native C function.  Based on the signature I am guessing that `code` is being read from and `key` is being written to.  If that is the case then try the following signature

```
[DllImport("SomeDll")]
public static extern void GetGeneratedKey(
  [In] string code,
  [In] int length,
  StringBuilder key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `string`. Should just work.

Answer (score 0):

everybody for the quick reply and support
I used method signature like the below

VC++  method signature
void GetGeneratedKey(char *code, int len, char *key)

C# signature
[DllImport("SomeDll")]
public static extern void GetGeneratedKey(byte[] code, int len, bute key);

nRk

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Unmanaged case.

C++

```
 void GetGeneratedKey(
 const char *code,
 int length,
 char *key);
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Some.Dll")]
public static extern void GetGeneratedKey(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string code,
int length,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder key);
```